# How to generate HTML and CSS dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

I am trying to integrate [this photo album](http://youhack.me/demo/g%20plus%20photo/) in my asp.net website. I am selecting urls of 3 images from database and and displaying those 3 images from a particular album. Now the problem is that what if the user has multiple Albums? It should be able to generate as many Jquery albums on the page as there are in the database associated with that user.

```
 <div class="image_stack" style="margin-left:300px" runat="server" >
 <img  id="photo1" class="stackphotos"  runat="server" clientidmode="static" >
    <img  id="photo2" class="stackphotos"  runat="server" clientidmode="static">
     <img   id="photo3" class="stackphotos"  runat="server" clientidmode="static" > 
     </div>

 public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dboperation dbo = new dboperation();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string q = "select photourl ,AlbumName  from PhotoAlbum where UserId=42";
        dt = dbo.Getdt(q);
        string a = dt.Rows[0]["photourl"].ToString();
        string b = dt.Rows[1]["photourl"].ToString();
        string c = dt.Rows[2]["photourl"].ToString();

        photo1.Src = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        photo2.Src = b.Substring(1, b.Length - 1);
        photo3.Src = c.Substring(1, c.Length - 1);

        q = "  select PhotoAlbum.AlbumId,PhotoAlbum.AlbumName from PhotoAlbum where UserId=42";

         dt = dbo.Getdt(q);
         drpalbum.DataSource = dt;
         drpalbum.DataTextField = "albumname";
         drpalbum.DataValueField = "albumid";
         drpalbum.DataBind();
    }
```

Let me know if you need to see more code.

Comment: 1) Please review _what if the user has multiple user?_

Comment: 2) Please clarify the context. WebForms, MVC, what is `drpalbum` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman multiple albums (sorry)

Comment: @HenkHolterman asp.net C# 4.0 and i am using sql server 2008

Comment: The SQl stuff is not so relevant. But I still don't know how you (want to) make a page.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i am displaying the albums which user has using jquery. Each album has many pics. And the album previews top 3 pics which are within that album. So far i have just 1 album. http://snag.gy/gtsO2.jpg 
I want to create more of these albums dynamically depending on number of albums that user has.

Answer (score 1):

use simply a 'div'

in which like this

```
//HTML (.aspx)
<div id="MyDiv" runat="server" > </div>

//CodeBehind (.aspx.cs)
MyDiv.innerHTML = "Your HTML & CSS or Script code here CODE";
```

it will be applied to whole div

EDIT 1:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

import above

Comment: i am getting 'Error 19 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' does not contain a definition for 'innerHTML' and no extension method 'innerHTML' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
'

Comment: check your codebehind if there is an error of this type it should display it, probably an import issue.

Comment: yes you will have to import using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have a HTML element on your page communicating against the server like this,

Pretty much identical to Photons

```
//HTML - Does not have to be div could be anything like <p>, <div>, <a> etc.
<span id="SomeHTMLElement" runat="server" ></span>

//C#
SomeHTMLElement.innerHTML = "Any text you want to your page (text, HTML, script and/or CSS";
```

Comment: span is generally used for designing purpose not for adding elements it is much different than div

Comment: div will take up the width, and you used it :)

On the note there is a big difference thats not really true. The main difference between div and span is the display:block;(div) and display:inline;(span), if you want you can write <jump></jump> and set the style manually with the same result.

Comment: ya div will take that coz we likely to show some element in between but what generally we use to show elements that doesn't belong to too much style we do use div although you're right that  <jump id="myJump"></jump> will also work

Answer (score 0):

checkout this to generate HTML and CSS dynamically in asp.net

http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter